# Dynamics of Triangle Iterates by angle bisector

Tags: geometry, analysis, fractals, angle

I'm attempting to prove what is demonstrated in [this Wolfram demo](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DynamicsOfTriangleIterates/)

Let $T_0$ be an arbitrary triangle with vertices $A_0,B_0$and $C_0$,and let $T_1$ be the triangle formed by the intersection points of the angle bisectors of $T_0$ on its three sides .Construct $T_2,T_3...$in the same manner.

> Prove that the sequence$\{T_n\}_{n\geq0}$converges (in shape) to an
>   equilateral triangle!

This question haved been solved by [this paper:On Sequences of Nested Triangles](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257618944_On_Sequences_of_Nested_Triangles).However ,this paper uses **MAPLE to perform and check** the calculation! So I'm curious that can we solve this question through only (mathematics) analysis?(May be ..it is difficult)
Thanks.

Comment: Try this https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3618524.pdf?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents